# Privacy with Ubuntu Phone

Tags: privacy

I am very security conscious and am reluctant to use Google products, including android because of the data Google collect. For anyone interested, I've posted the joke that is the information they collect below. I've read the privacy policy that the Ubuntu phone steals from you & I am wondering if there is a way to disable every single piece of personally identifiable information to Ubuntu? Otherwise I just cannot purchase the device.

reasons not to use google andriod
things they record/take from your phone:
-youtube searches, youtube video's viewed
-your hardware model, operating system version, UUID (unique ID to identify your device, including your EMEI number)
-your phone number
-any search queries
-numbers called along with a timestamp & duration
-IP address
-hardware settings
-browser type & language, and any website you visit with a timestamp and date
-your GPS location when it's active
-Wifi Access points and nearby mobile towers
-personal information on your local storage within the phone

Answer (score 0):

Sniffing through the source code and modifying lines of code related to GPS and other stuff and then re compiling the distro. I am pretty sure that there are some closed source drivers in use anyway, so I don't really see the point.

http://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/new-ubuntu-phone-won-t-truly-be-open-source-article/1574

Chances are, someone or something is watching unless you use a cardboard phone.

Comment: "Closed source" doesn't necessarily mean "no privacy", although it's harder to protect against. Even if someone tried to do something under the radar (usually not the case: loss of privacy is most often described in detail in the small print of the licence, but people don't seem to care...), it would still be very difficult for a closed source driver to systematically send meaningful amounts of information to any particular destination without being detected by at least one user. After that, the company could be in for significant legal problems. This is very rare, I believe.